# LEMP server generating index.html in /root folder

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

[image: This is putty showing the gazillion index.html files in /root folder]

This is putty showing the gazillion index.html files in /root folder

Whenever I login through ssh I see thousands of index.html files in the /root directory. Even though I delete them everytime they always reappear. And it seems like they have something to do with the website hits. I do not understand why this is happening.

I am running Nginx on Ubuntu with PHP 7.

Any clues would be helpful.. Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing your setup anyone else can only guess what happens here. First of all, I wonder why is there an index.html in the /root/ folder at all? You probably do not want to work as root on a public web server and the pubic contents should not reside in the root users home directory. (But for example in /var/www) Looks like a strange setup…

Comment: You could monitor the server and try to see what process is creating the files: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/is-it-possible-to-find-out-what-program-or-script-created-a-given-file. However, besides the file being called `index.html`, I don't see how this question fits here since it seems to be more of a linux-admin-question.

Comment: I have a LEMP setup. Exactly, I do not want to work on the root directory, that's why I am clueless which app is creating this.

Comment: Are you running any cron jobs?  Something like a wget?

Comment: _"I do not want to work on the root directory"_ - So where is your document root for the web server? Is it /root?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson no It's not /root I am using /var/www/html [at]Progrock Let me check that

Comment: @Progrock yeah I had a wget in crontab :-D now please tell me how do I get rid of these files and still keep that wget command in crontab

Comment: First, decide where you want the output to go instead.

Comment: I just wanted to trigger a GET request without having to store the data anywhere. @MichaelHampton